# Replace host in Uri

Tags: c#, .net, uri

What is the nicest way of replacing the host-part of an Uri using .NET?

I.e.:

```
string ReplaceHost(string original, string newHostName);
//...
string s = ReplaceHost("http://oldhostname/index.html", "newhostname");
Assert.AreEqual("http://newhostname/index.html", s);
//...
string s = ReplaceHost("http://user:pass@oldhostname/index.html", "newhostname");
Assert.AreEqual("http://user:pass@newhostname/index.html", s);
//...
string s = ReplaceHost("ftp://user:pass@oldhostname", "newhostname");
Assert.AreEqual("ftp://user:pass@newhostname", s);
//etc.
```

System.Uri does not seem to help much.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

[System.UriBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder) is what you are after...

```
string ReplaceHost(string original, string newHostName) {
    var builder = new UriBuilder(original);
    builder.Host = newHostName;
    return builder.Uri.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I would have recommended the Uri class, but I would have been wrong. Good answer.

Comment: Works great, just note that if you read the Query property, it is prepended with a ?, and if you set the Query Property with a string beginning with ?, another ? will be prepended.

Comment: You'll have to handle ports, if they are specified in either original or new.

Answer (score 45):

As @Ishmael says, you can use System.UriBuilder. Here's an example:

```
// the URI for which you want to change the host name
var oldUri = Request.Url;

// create a new UriBuilder, which copies all fragments of the source URI
var newUriBuilder = new UriBuilder(oldUri);

// set the new host (you can set other properties too)
newUriBuilder.Host = "newhost.com";

// get a Uri instance from the UriBuilder
var newUri = newUriBuilder.Uri;
```

Comment: I suspect it might be better to obtain the `Uri` instance by calling `newUriBuilder.Uri` rather than formatting and parsing it.

Comment: @Sam you're right, the [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.uri.aspx) property is a much better option. Thanks. Updated.

Comment: Careful of the `.Uri` call. If you have something in that `UriBuilder` that does not translate to a valid Uri, it will throw.

So for example if you need a wildcard host `*` you can set `.Host` to that, but if you call `.Uri` it will throw.

If you call `UriBuilder.ToString()` it will return the Uri with the wildcard in place.