# Add prefix string in URL string

Tags: c#

User input the url string in a textbox and I need to add a string "cmd" if not available .

Please suggest how to achieve this,

```
string cmdUrl = AddPrefix("https://google.com");

static string AddPrefix(string inputUrl)
{
   return formattedUrl;// want to return https://cmd.google.com if the string cmd not added already in url
}
```

Comment: There's functionality for parsing a URL/URI into its component parts and then manipulating it. Did you do any research for built in methods to do that in .NET?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL split in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029909/url-split-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can parse your url using `var parsedUrl = new Uri(inputUrl)`.
Then check if the host includes your substring like this: `parsedUrl.Host.StartsWith("cmd")`
If it does, return your original url else build your new one: `$"{parsedUrl.Scheme}://cmd.{parsedUrl.Host}{parsedUrl.PathAndQuery}"`