# ASP.NET Web API 2 - User Email Confirmation while registration

Tags: c#, asp.net, webapi2

I want to implement email / account confirmation via email while user registration.
But have difficulties with the following method, creation correct callbackUrl and a way how it should confirmed by application. Is there a best way to solve that?
I got the following resources:
[this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24203650/generate-reset-password-link-in-webapi)

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
            var callbackUrl = Url.Action(
               "ConfirmEmail", "Account", 
               new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, 
               protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

            await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, 
               "Confirm your account", 
               "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" 
                                               + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
            // ViewBag.Link = callbackUrl;   // Used only for initial demo.
            return View("DisplayEmail");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't understood what is your problem. Could you clarify?

Comment: Hello Steve! How to build callbackUrl properly for webapi? When the confirmation link comes to user and user clicks it, does web api standard controller has methods to catch the registration data?

Comment: Gentlemen, any idea on these pls?

Comment: Probably has been solved here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245065/asp-net-web-api-generate-url-using-url-action