# How to enter ip address into Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uitextfield, ip, user-input

I have 3 separate code that requires me to change the ip address manually whenever I am testing outside. therefore I am trying to enter an inputfield in unity so that I can enter it once and it will be used by all my code but I have no idea how to do it.

[image]
This is just a simple input field that I have placed in my Homepage.cs page to enter the ip address

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HomePage : MonoBehaviour
{
public Text playerDisplay;
public InputField ipField;
public Button submitButton;

private void Start()
{
    if (DBManager.LoggedIn)
    {
        playerDisplay.text = "Player: " + DBManager.username;
    }

}

public void QuitGame()
{
    Debug.Log("Quit!");
    Application.Quit();
}
}
```

This is my Homepage code that I just put the InputField 'ipField' only. The input from here I would like to transfer it to

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Registration : MonoBehaviour
{
public InputField nameField;
public InputField passwordField;
public Text error1 = null;
public Text error2 = null;

public Button submitButton;

readonly string postUrl = "http://localhost/sqlconnect/register.php";
```

my Registration.cs page. This is just a part of the code, I only put the relevant part. What I want to replace is the 'localhost' from the readonly string to the inputfield from my Homepage.cs page. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace host in Uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479799/replace-host-in-uri)

Comment: How do i call it from my Registration.cs, because I tried using the unity code by typing string ipAddress = Homepage.findObjectofType<> and there is an error saying i cannot convert it to string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are multiple ways. One of them might be using [`FindObjectOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html) in order to get a reference to the `Homepage` component. Then you can access all its `public` members like in your case the `ipField` which is an [`InputField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField.html) so you can simply read out its [`InputField.text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-text.html)

```
ipAddress = FindObjectOfType<Homepage>().ipField.text;
```

In case there is only one instance of `Homepage` anyway.

---

If possible you should directly reference it in `Registration` using either a `public` or [`[SerializeField] private`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html) field like

```
public class Registration : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Reference this via the Unity Inspector by drag&drop the according GameObject here
    [SerializeField] private Homepage homepage;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // You could still have a fallback here
        if(! homepage) homepage = FindObjectOfType<Homepage>();
    }

    ...
}
```

and then later simply use

```
ipAddress = homepage.ipField.text;
```

Note that `FindObjectOfType` fails if the according object is inactive or the compomemt disabled!

---

You can also go fancy and comply with the encapsulation principles by providing `public` only the very needed thing using a [read-only property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)

```
public class Homepage : MonoBehaviour
{
    // This still allows to reference the object in the Inspector 
    // but prevents direct access from other scripts
    [SerializeField] private InputField ipField;

    // This is a public ReadOnly property for reading the IP from other scripts
    public string IP => ipField.text;

    ...
}
```

Then back in the `Registartion` you would simply use

```
ipAdress = homepage.IP;
```

---

Finally specific for an IP/URL field you could use a [Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-dns-hostname-or-ip-address) to check the input for validity.

Comment: Thank you so much, took me awhile to understand and implement(bit of a beginner), but this solved it for me. I chose your second solution

Comment: @CodingNeeded glad to help :) the second is actually the better one since `FindObjectOfType` is quite expensive and already referencing stuff via the Inspector prevents this overhead ;)